# App Icon Not Updating on External Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

I have uploaded all the correct sized .png images into my app's place to add app icons (sorry I don't know what it is called :p) and have deleted and re-installed the app back onto an external simulator (an iPad 2) multiple times, and it still has the default app icon, the white square with black lines.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your image assets folder? Are there any warnings?

Answer (score 0):

Often there is problem with cashing of the device. Even if you has deleted all resources it will still show old one for some time. I do not know how to fix it in time. For was helpful to wait about a two hours and than the new one appears. Actually if someone know how to avoid such casing, I would love to heard.

Answer (score 0):

do you set App icons source to AppIcon in TAGRETS
[image]